# warning: cannot scan executable section for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, cocos2d-x

I am trying to build a game using cocos2d-x. While compiling using cygwin for armeabi-v7a i get the following warnings

```
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 89 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(png.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 152 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngget.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 88 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngpread.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 38 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngread.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 88 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngread.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 78 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngrtran.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 107 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngrtran.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 117 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngrtran.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 147 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngrtran.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 56 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngrutil.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 131 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngrutil.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 181 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngrutil.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 146 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngset.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 82 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngwrite.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 16 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngwutil.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 101 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngwutil.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 181 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/png.a(pngwutil.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 23 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jccoefct.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 12 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jchuff.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 71 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jchuff.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 16 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jcmaster.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 9 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jcparam.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 41 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jcsample.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 35 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdatasrc.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 36 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdcolor.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 32 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdhuff.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 19 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdinput.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 4 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdmarker.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 62 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdmarker.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 20 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdmerge.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 8 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jfdctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 24 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jfdctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 36 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jfdctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 73 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jfdctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 113 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jfdctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 4 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jidctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 40 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jidctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 52 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jidctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 64 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jidctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 84 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jidctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 112 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jidctint.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 8 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jquant2.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 12 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jmemmgr.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 33 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jcarith.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 33 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/jpeg.a(jdarith.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 89 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(entities.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 68 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(encoding.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 266 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(encoding.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 68 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(error.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 77 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parserInternals.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 162 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parserInternals.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 75 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 190 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 280 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 320 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 340 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 375 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 460 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 490 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 510 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 515 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 560 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
E:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: cannot scan executable section 600 of ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/xml2.a(parser.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
```

I am using android-ndk-r8d. Does anyone know what is causing this warning or how to remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a known "issue" (behaviour) of the new linker that was introduced in R8C. See [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40794). These warnings can result from having stripped non-global symbols from the objects files that the linker needs to perform fixups.

That discussion yielded two suggested workarounds:

1) Remove all instances of `strip -x` in your makefile (if any exist).

2) Build with `make STRIP=`

Comment: i had seen this issue and its solution but did not understand how to fix it since my make file did not have any `strip -x`. I am new to native development so please explain. am i supposed to run the make file in my application  or the file named `make` in NDK

Comment: I'm seconding this question - it's not clear how to apply this fix for an Android NDK build.  Do we need to manually tweak the build files in the NDK?